# Align Elements HTML/CSS float or display: inline-block

Tags: html, css

Can anyone help me out with this problem?
You can't change HTML structure, but you have to adjust CSS in order for this to be in same line if that's possible...

Thanks in advance!

Here's the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/NgfSF/24/

```
.description {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.description1 {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

img {
    background-color:#FFF;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:solid black 1px;
    float: left;
}
```

EDIT: 
For the one who will need this in the future, text has to be display: block and image just float, left or right.

Comment: No one *has to* anything around here.

Answer (score 1):

remove the float from `.description1` also added a padding to description to improve aesthetics. this because you can't change the html part as you said.

```
.description {
   float: left;
   padding: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NgfSF/26/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/NgfSF/25/

```
.description {
    width: 10%;
}

.description1 {
    width: 90%;
}
```

Just give them a width under 100% when added together, like above. Adjust accordingly.

Comment: Bear in mind that when the widths are done in % and add up to 100% it can cause the elements to wrap. Depending on how the browser calculates the widths, rounding issues can cause the total width to be greater than 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Put the image in the same div as the paragraph you want it next to...give the image a class and style it like that...you don't have to put it in a separate div

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
.description {
    float: left;
}

img {
    background-color:#FFF;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:solid black 1px;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the css to this,

```
.description {
    float: left;
}

.description1 {
}

img {
    background-color:#FFF;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:solid black 1px;
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NgfSF/29/